# new google.maps.LatLngBounds() and memory leak in Android and google maps

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there is a way to clear (delete) a google.maps.LatLngBounds(), as I have one with some point and for example clicking on a button I want just have a new point in the map. So, having something like bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds().extend(point) if bounds var already existed wouldn't create a memory leak?, I mean, previous bounds will remain unassigned.
FYI: It works, but I don't like to create a memory leak.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was said that is might depend on each browser javascript engine.